# Connect 10 LEDs using 5 volt current

Tags: voltage, led, resistors

I have 10 yellow-colored LEDs and ten 220 ohm resistors. I don't have any power source except the Arduino's 5 volt itself.

Is it possible to power all the 10 LEDs using the 5 volt equally? Or will the volts slowly diminish as the LEDs are powered along a series circuit? Also, is it possible to use only one resistor in the series or do I need to use a parallel circuit with one resistor after every LED?

Please help, I'm completely new to electronics and building a arduino project for my school expo.

Comment: A link to the data sheet might help but 5V is not a current.  A typical yellow LED has a forward voltage of 2.0 to 2.4V so each LED takes 14mA max each with a 220ohm series resistor so 140mA total.  You should be OK an Arduino is capable of supplying around 400mA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUnG32.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Consider this 100mA layout for 2S5P array. You can always recompute R1 if this is blinding too bright !  Some are > 10 cd such as message signs.

[image]

You better read a datasheet so you know how not to handle them and how not to solder them.  (ESD and 5sec max solder time >5mm from base.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm a complete noob in these matters. Can you please explain your answer since I can't understand the schematic.

Comment: The flat edge on 5mm LEDs is the cathode or negative side which is the flat line bottom of the symbol. I only showed 1 string. YOu replicate this string in parallel 5 times.  What do you not understand?  Put the link to LED specs or equiv in question

Comment: @SayanjyotiDas alternatively use your 220 Ohm resistors instead of the 40 Ohm. This will give you 3.6mA through each LED which should be bright enough for most LEDs.

Comment: What is the purpose of your project?

Comment: It's actually a nuclear reactor simulator.

Comment: I wanted to light 10 LEDs at once using the Arduino

Comment: Can you help me on how it could be done in the best way? I understand the software part, please help me on the hardware.

Comment: If just short range  indicators driven by Arduino 5V 25 Ohm driver you can drive direct with active low or high and use 40 Ohm for really bright or 220 Ohm for dim

Comment: If I use 40 Ohm resistors, won't the voltage be too high and the LED will melt or get damaged?

Comment: Not with two in series.  Treat the Diodes like tiny battery voltages or Zeners ( another example of a Diode) THen learn Ohm's Law.   Since you shared the purpose, I assumed you want 10 indicators at reasonably low brightness using only 3 of 20mA

Comment: Ok, I get it. Thank you for your help :-)

Comment: If you use 1 LED per string that is 5 volts minus 2.1= 2.9 volts. then divide by resistance 220 ohms = 13 mA is now 13/20= 63% of maximum suggested brightness. But I suggested 3mA if your LEDs are really bright. that are visible a few blocks away. Only you can tell us what you have

Comment: You can also use 3.3V if that's what Arduino is using then reduce R with Ohm's Law

Answer (score 4):

Firstly the Voltage isn't all that you need to know. The Amperage that can be drawn at that voltage is also important to know. In your Aurduino documentation it will tell you what the maximum current that can be sourced is. As already said in the comments, it will be around 400mA.

Current or Amps is how much power you have available, not Volts.

We don't know what LEDs you are using, but they will specify how much current they use. It will be a number in mA (milliamps). A typical 5mm yellow LED uses around 20mA.

Then you have your resistors, which Ohms Law (V=IR) will tell you how much current they will soak up. Your typical 5mm yellow LED will have a forward voltage of around 2.1V, so we will just make it a even number and say they are drawing around 15mA (it's actually less than that).

So that makes it around 15mA per set. Times 10 that's 150mA. If your Arduino can supply 150mA or more then you're good.

Comment: How did you end up with 35 mA? Lools like you added 2A+15mA. Hpwever, the current you calculated (correctly) that the resistors are drawing is the **same** current each LED is drawing, because they are in series. So, each set does 15mA.

Comment: I'm curious who thoughtlessly voted this answer up...

Comment: Hey, up vote just means you found it useful. It doesn't have to be correct :p

Comment: How can wrong info in this case be useful? Leaves me guessing. Anyway, +1 for the nice (corrected) answer.